# Acessar dados no Firebase com Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Estou tentando acessar os dados conforme a imagem. Preciso trazer as informações que estão dentro do documento.
Estou tentando utilizar o seguinte código:

```
final QuerySnapshot result1 = await Future.value(Firestore.instance
          .collection("pesquisas").getDocuments());
final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents1 = result1.documents;
print(documents1.elementAt(0).documentID.toString());
```

Mas retorna somente o documento, no caso 02022021. Mas preciso acessar os campos, os dados que estão neste documento para preencher uma lista. Segue a imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agradeço e aguardo retorno!

Comment: Edita a sua pergunta e adiciona o código que utilizou para buscar os dados, para entendermos melhor. (Ali acima tu só colocou uma linha)

Comment: Obrigado pelo feedback. Atualizado!

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se é a melhor solução, mas me atendeu!

```
void _addDate() async {

    DateTime today = new DateTime.now();
    String dataCorreta =
        "${today.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}${today.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}${today.year.toString()}";

    final QuerySnapshot result = await Future.value(Firestore.instance
        .collection("pesquisas")
        .where(FieldPath.documentId, isEqualTo: dataCorreta)
        .limit(1)
        .getDocuments());

    final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result.documents;
    if (documents.length == 0) {
      Firestore.instance
          .collection("pesquisas")
          .document(dataCorreta)
          .setData(data);
    } else {
      documents.forEach((element) {
        setState(() {
          _counterDissatisfied =
              int.parse(element.data.values.elementAt(0).toString());
          _counterVerySatisfied =
              int.parse(element.data.values.elementAt(2).toString());
          _counterSatisfied =
              int.parse(element.data.values.elementAt(3).toString());
        });
      });
    }
  }
```